# Power BI - Filter Tile Change Color Selection

Tags: powerbi

I have a filter Tiled style. I manage to change selections font color but I m wondering if there is a setting to change selected background color.

For example to change the change selection background to blue.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

standard filter visual cannot change but you can try custom visual "Chiclet Slicer" and make color change:

[image]